# String splitting into parts and store to CSV using JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, string, export-to-csv

I have data on different formats. I want that first the **Quantity** is extracted from the input string than the **Unit** is extracted and the remaining text should consider as an **item**.

**Code.java**

```
  public String itemsProcesing(List<String> items) throws IOException {
        List<String> list = items;
        List<String> unitList = Arrays.asList("g", "tbsp", "cm", "kg"");
        List<String> quantityList = Arrays.asList("Full", "Quarter", "Half", "3 Quarter", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0");

        for (String s : list) {
            String[] strArr = s.split(" ");
            if (strArr.length == 2) {
                String newStr = rewriteString(strArr, quantityList);
                strArr = newStr.split(" ");
            }
            String[] itemLine = new String[3];
            for (int i = 0; i < strArr.length; i++) {
                String str = strArr[i];
                int index = findValueLocation(str, unitList);
                itemLine[index] = str;
            }
            String line = createLineForCSV(itemLine);
            writeToFile(line);

        }


        return "done";
    }

    private static int findValueLocation(String str, List<String> unitList) {
         boolean b = Pattern.matches("\\d{1,3}|\\d/\\d|\\d/\\d[*]\\d|\\d{1,3}[*]\\d{1,3}|\\d{1,3}[*]\\d{1,3}|\\d{1,3}[-]\\d{1,3}|\\d{1,3} [-] \\d{1,3}|\\d.\\d|\\\\d{1,3} - \\\\d{1,3}| \\\\d{1,3} - \\\\d{1,3}| \\\\d{1,3}-\\\\d{1,3}", str);
        if (b) {
            return 0;
        }

        for (String unit : unitList) {
            if (unit.equals(str)) {
                return 1;
            }
        }
        return 2;
    }

    private static String createLineForCSV(String[] itemLine) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(itemLine[0]).append(",");
        sb.append(itemLine[1]).append(",");
        sb.append(itemLine[2]);
        return sb.toString();
    }

    private static void writeToFile(String line) throws IOException {
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("csv_file.csv", true));
        writer.write(line);
        writer.newLine();
        writer.close();
    }

    private static String rewriteString(String[] arr, List<String> quantityList) {
        String strOne = arr[0];
        String strTwo = arr[1];
        String newStr = "";
        for (String quantity : quantityList) {
            if (strOne.contains(quantity)) {
                // 8g carrots becomes "8 g carrots"
                newStr = quantity + " " + strOne.substring(quantity.length()) + " " + strTwo;
                break;
            } else if (strTwo.contains(quantity)) {
                newStr = quantity + " " + strTwo.substring(quantity.length()) + " " + strOne;
                break;
            }
        }
        return newStr;
    }
```

> **Input data** 
>   1-2 tbsp soya sauce
>
> **Ouptut** : 1-2,tbsp,sauce
>
> **Required Output**: 1-2,tbsp,soya sauce

How I could get the required results.

Comment: If the problem is only the "space" before the "," you can just use
 sb.append(itemLine[0].trim()).append(","); ... trim gets rid of the space characters at the start or the end of a string

Comment: @JavaMan No Sir. This isn't the issue only. I have updated the question.
I want the rest of the string after extracting the **quantity** and **unit** from an input string will consider as an **item**.

Comment: How free is the actual format of the input? Is it always `1` `1-2` `1/2`, or it can contain spaces too, like `1 - 2` or `1 / 2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here at this line in items processing : 
`int index = findValueLocation(str, unitList);
 itemLine[index] = str;`

The 'findValueLocation' function will return 2 for both strings 'soya' and 'sauce'. Now it overwrites the string 'soya' and writes 'sauce' on index 2. You should concatenate the string if the value being returned is 2.

`

```
int index = findValueLocation(str, unitList);
 if(index == 2){
     itemLine[index] += str;
 }else{
     itemLine[index] = str;
 }
```

`

Answer (score 2):

I think it is enough to build an exhaustive list of measurement units only, and split the string along that. Then you do not need to parse the amount.

Something like this:

```
Pattern p=Pattern.compile("(.*?)\\s*(tbsp|k?g|cup|c?m)\\s*(.*)");
List<String> tests=Arrays.asList(
  "16g salt",
  "1 kg apple",
  "1 1/2 tbsp sugar");
for(String s:tests){
  Matcher m=p.matcher(s);
  if(m.matches())
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(m.group(1),m.group(2),m.group(3)));
}
```

Output (from https://ideone.com/9kbozK):

> ```
> [16, g, salt]
> [1, kg, apple]
> [1 1/2, tbsp, sugar]
> ```

In real life there should be an `else` branch to catch possible errors (or unrecognized units) in input.

Answer (score 1):

You could put it all in one horrible regex like
(it may need some fine tuning)

```
"((\\d+([/\\\\*]\\d+)?)\\s*(-\\s*\\d+([/\\\\*]\\d+)?)?\\s*(Full|Quarter|Half|3 Quarter)?)\\s*(g|tbsp|cm|kg)?\\s*(\\w*.*)"
```

and pick group 1, group 7 and group 8.

I wasn't quite sure where to put the Quarter etc, quantity, unit or both, in your source you use it for formatting, as i see...

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RecepieSplitter {

    private static final Pattern INGREDIENT_PATTERN = Pattern.compile(
            "((\\d+([/\\\\*]\\d+)?)\\s*(-\\s*\\d+([/\\\\*]\\d+)?)?\\s*(Full|Quarter|Half|3 Quarter)?)\\s*(g|tbsp|cm|kg)?\\s*(\\w*.*)");

    public static List<String> getParts(String ingredient) {
        Matcher matcher = INGREDIENT_PATTERN.matcher(ingredient);
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            return Arrays.asList(matcher.group(1), matcher.group(7), matcher.group(8));
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(RecepieSplitter.getParts("1-2 tbsp soya sauce"));
        System.out.println(RecepieSplitter.getParts("8g carorts"));
        System.out.println(RecepieSplitter.getParts("1/4kg carorts"));
        System.out.println(RecepieSplitter.getParts("1/4 - 1/2g carorts"));
        System.out.println(RecepieSplitter.getParts("1 - 2Quarter carorts"));
    }
}
```

Output:

> [1-2 , tbsp, soya sauce]
>
> [8, g, carorts]
>
> [1/4, kg, carorts]
>
> [1/4 - 1/2, g, carorts]
>
> [1 - 2Quarter, null, carorts]